# Magento place category block in div

Tags: html, css, magento

I have been playing around with different styles of pages, but there's one thing that I can't do. Which is placing the CODNITIVE category block in a div.

Example:

[image: The perfect webpage]

For some reason I can't seem to find a way to place it somewhere.
If you have any questions, feel free to ask.